# where condition in Insert/Update Trigger not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

This is my trigger:

```
  Create trigger Points
  on Posts
  after insert, update
  As
  declare @Id int;
  declare @value int;

  select @value= Count(i.Message) from Posts i;
  select @Id = [PostedBy] from inserted;

  update AspNetUsers set User_points = @value * 3
  where @Id = @Id
```

Here, at the last line, where condition always fails.Its not picking correct Id and updating same value in User_Points column in all rows not in particular rows.

I have written an insert statement to check what value i get back like this:

```
   insert into Employee_Demo(PostedBy, TotalCount)
   values (@postedby,@value );
```

here, i am getting correct @postedby value in table.
Previosly, i was trying this:

```
    create trigger Points
    on Posts
    after insert, update
    As
   declare @value int
   declare @postedby int
   select @value= Count(Message) from Posts
   select @postedby = PostedBy from inserted

   update AspNetUsers set User_points = @value * 3
   where Id = @postedby
```

please please someone help me. how to update only single row based on Id.
One more thing, PostedBy is not the primary key in post table.It is foreign key to aspnetuser table and it contains id value of user who has posted the message as u can see in below image.
[image]

tried this too:

```
 update AspNetUsers set User_points = @value * 3
FROM INSERTED INNER JOIN Posts ON  INSERTED.PostedBy = Posts.PostedBy
INNER JOIN AspNetUsers ON AspNetUsers.Id = inserted.PostedBy
```

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` or `UPDATE` statement that causes this trigger to fire affects 25 rows at once, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` and `deleted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `select @Id = [PostedBy] from inserted;` - it's non-deterministic, you'll get **one arbitrary row** and you will be **ignoring all other rows**.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are comparing same Variable in where clause, where you are supposed to compare DB field with Variable.

Comment: in the last one i have used that too update AspNetUsers set User_points = @value * 3
   where Id = [at]postedby

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working with this query dont know how it happens

```
 update AspNetUsers set User_points = @value * 3
 where Id = (Select PostedBy from inserted)
```

and removing the declaration of @Id or @PostedBy. when i declared those variable and then assign value from inserted to those variable and then use that variable value in where then it was not working.
Instead, directly getting value from inserted table in where condition works.

Comment: This trigger is broken. `inserted` may contain 0, 1 or *multiple* rows. In the latter case, this trigger will break with an error along the lines of "subquery returned more than one value". You need to write a *set-based* trigger that correctly deals with multiple rows in `inserted`. You might also want to consider replacing all of this with just a view (possibly indexed if performance is an issue) since you seem to be storing data that is easily *calculated* from other data (which just opens the opportunity for the data to be inconsistent)

Comment: I think u are right sir. i dont know much about that. As far as i know, inserted is a magical table which keeps records of latest insertion.So, whenever a new data is inserted in post table trigger would check for Id from inserted table and update that row.Anyways , how to write set based trigger here any help appreciated @Damien_The_Unbeliever